# Changing position of element in array

Tags: java

I'm not allowed to import anything so java.util.arrays/Import lists can't be used.

So far I've got this:

```
public class MyArrayList {
public String[] arrays;
int counter = 0;

public MyArrayList() {
    arrays = new String[5];

}

public void add(String element) {
    if (counter >= arrays.length) {
        String[] newarray = new String[arrays.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            newarray[i] = arrays[i];
        }
        arrays = newarray;
    }
    arrays[counter] = element;
    counter++;
}
    public void set(String element, int position) { //This is the code that will change pos
    element = arrays[arrays.length - 1];
    for (int y = arrays.length - 1; y > position; y--)
        arrays[y] = arrays[y - 1];
    arrays[position] = element;

}

public class MyArrayListTest {

static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList();


public static void printZoo() {
    System.out.print("The zoo now holds " + zoo.size() + " animals: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < zoo.size(); j++) System.out.print(zoo.get(j) + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Testing constructor, add(object) and size() ");
    zoo.add("Ant");
    zoo.add("Bison");
    zoo.add("Camel");
    zoo.add("Dog");
    zoo.add("Elephant");
    zoo.add("Frog");
    zoo.add("Giraffe");
    zoo.add("Horse");
    printZoo();
    zoo.set("Frog",0);
    zoo.set("Camel",2);
    zoo.set("Dog",4);
    zoo.set("Elephant",6);
    zoo.set("Giraffe",7);
    zoo.set("Horse",5);
    zoo.set("Ant",1);
    zoo.set("Bison",3);
    printZoo();
    System.out.println();
```

So what I want to do is make the set method change the positions of elements in 
the array.

This is what gets printed out:

The zoo now holds 8 animals: Ant Bison Camel Dog Elephant Frog Giraffe Horse

The zoo now holds 8 animals: Horse Elephant Ant Giraffe Bison Frog Dog Camel

So locations do change but it's not in the right order.

It SHOULD be :

The zoo now holds 8 animals: Frog Ant Camel Bison Dog Horse Elephant Giraffe

Comment: Please provide a clear, concise, and specific description of your problem/task, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and why that MCVE doesn't work.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes that's already provided, just focus on the `set` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Clearly, it isn't. OP never explains the problem, and the code is most definitely not an MCVE if there's only one relevant part.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes OP is very explicit: *This is what gets printed out: The zoo now holds 8 animals: Ant Bison Camel Dog Elephant Frog Giraffe Horse The zoo now holds 8 animals: Horse Elephant Ant Giraffe Bison Frog Dog Camel* and the problem is below: *locations do change but it's not in the right order*. So, you just have to **read the code** (yes, that's the MCVE) and see it's short enough to understand and replicate the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I saw that. What I didn't see was what the right order should be.

Comment: Well, that needs explanation, but the MVCE is already provided. And again, the problem seems to be in the `set` method.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Sorry I edited it, Hopefully it should be easier to understand.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah it's something to do with my set method most likely but I don't get what it is. Quiet a new Java programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you overriding the value of element in set function? You have no variable which holds the value of wanted property then. Look at your code again.

```
public void set(String element, int position) { 
    element = arrays[arrays.length - 1]; // at this point, you no longer
                                         // know what the element was

    //and now you shift the list by 1 element
    for (int y = arrays.length - 1; y > position; y--)
    arrays[y] = arrays[y - 1];
    arrays[position] = element;
}
```

You are just shifting the list.
You could try doing that in this way

```
public void set(String element, int position) {
    String tmp = arrays[position];
    arrays[position] = element;
    ...
    ... //here check if element you have set was already inside the array
    ... //if it isn't, increase array length and put tmp at the end
    ... //if it is, put tmp in old index of element
}
```

I mean it's just a quick answer, without thinking about corner cases but it seems to me that your idea was a little bit incorrect.

Ok, here is complete solution to your problem :)

```
public void set(String element, int position) {
    if (arrays[position].equals(element))
        return;

    String tmp = arrays[position];
    arrays[position] = element;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        if (arrays[i].equals(element) && i != position) {
            arrays[i] = tmp;
            return;
        }
    }
    add(tmp);
}
```